# Could not locate a layer <...> with id <...> GWC configuration seems to be out of synch

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Geoserver fails to start with exceptions:

```
29 Geg 10:50:51 WARN [org.geoserver] - Failed to load layer group 'NP2014.xml'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Layer group within a workspace (W1) can not contain resources from other workspace: W2
```

and

```
Could not locate a layer or layer group with id LayerGroupInfoImpl--76c8fe6e:156cfaae875:-1156 within GeoServer configuration, the GWC configuration seems to be out of synch
```

Did not find the accordind layer .xml file in gwc-layers.

Link to the catalina.out https://ufile.io/aq41f

Comment: what did you do? try deleting the cache and restart?

Comment: Last thing that was done that I know is that some stores had their workspaces changed. I was going to restart Tomcat go get fresh logs of geoserever, but decided to manualy restart geoserver first. After I shut it down via Tomcat's manager it was unable to go up again.

Comment: I think I got. Layer group was assigned to different workspace while member stores were not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that few layer groups were assigned to different workspace while member stores were not. Then geoserver was stopped for a restart and was unable to go up because:

```
Layer group within a workspace (W1) can not contain resources from other workspace: W2
```

After manualy moving errorous layer group xml files from ".../data/workspaces/W1/layergroups" to ".../data/workspaces/W2/layergroups", deleting the xml files in ".../data/workspaces/W1/layergroups" and also making sure all layergroup xmls have correct WorkspaceInfoImpl I tried to start geoserver and everything is fine so far.